# How to write scala code not like java code?

Tags: java, scala, coding-style

During an interview, the tech lead said my scala code was just like java code, but using scala api and he wanted me to improve on that.

I am a 3-year java developer and I began scala coding by following the MOOC on Coursera.

Can anyone tell me what is the problem and how can I improve it, please?

I got the job because of my Java acknowledge but the job is based on scala and the coding style is one thing to fix during the trial period.

```
object Extraction {

// IntelliJ use .idea/modules as current working directory
  val FilePathPre = "../../src/main/resources/"
  val UserIdFile = "lookup_user.csv"
  val ProductIdFile = "lookup_product.csv"
  val RatingFile = "agg_ratings.csv"

  def readFile(file: String): Iterator[((String, String), String, String)] = {
val Splitter = ","
Source.fromInputStream(this.getClass.getResourceAsStream(file)).getLines()
      .map(_.split(Splitter))
      .filter(_.size >= 4) // in case line is not valid
      .map(x => ((x(0), x(1)), x(2), x(3))) // (userId, ItemId), rating, time
  }

  def filePrinter(fileName: String, lines: mutable.Map[String, Int]) = {
val file = new File(fileName)
val bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))
lines.toArray.sortWith((a, b) => a._2 < b._2)
     .map(x => x._1 + "," + x._2.toString + "\n")
     .foreach(bw.write)
bw.close()
  }

  def aggFilePrinter(fileName: String, lines: mutable.Map[(Int, Int), Float]) = {
val file = new File(fileName)
val bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))
lines.foreach(x => {
     val line = x._1._1.toString + "," + x._1._2.toString + "," + (math.round(x._2 * 100.0) / 100.0).toFloat + "\n"
     bw.write(line)
   })
bw.close()
  }

  /**
* * une pénalité multiplicative de 0.95 est appliquée au rating
*   pour chaque jour d'écart avec le timestamp maximal de input.csv
*
* @param nowTime maximal timestamp at input.csv
* @param pastTime    current rating time
* @param rating  original rating
* @return final rating multiplied by 0.95 for every day interval from the maximal timestamp
*/
  def finalRating(nowTime: String, pastTime: String, rating: String): Float = {
val now =
  LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(nowTime.toLong), ZoneId.systemDefault())
val past =
  LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(pastTime.toLong), ZoneId.systemDefault())
val diff = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(past, now)
(math.pow(0.95, diff) * rating.toFloat).toFloat
  }

  /**
*
* @param file file to extract
*/
  def fileDispatcher(file: String) = {

    /**
  * get idIndice or increment to idIndice and put it to id map
  * @param id  id in String
  * @param idIndice id in Int
  * @param idMap userIdMap or productIdMap
  * @return (indice for id, max idIndice)
  */
def getIndice(id: String, idIndice: Int, idMap: mutable.Map[String, Int]): (Int, Int) = {
  idMap.get(id) match {
    case Some(i) => (i, idIndice)
    case None => {
      val indice = idIndice + 1
      idMap += (id -> indice)
      (indice, indice)
    }
  }
}

// 1. scan the file the find the max time
val maxTime = readFile(file).reduce((a, b) => if(a._3 > b._3) a else b)._3

// 2. apply rating condition, calculate rating and return only valid rating lines
val validLines = readFile(file).map(x => (x._1, finalRating(maxTime.toString, x._3, x._2))).filter(_._2 > 0.01)

// 3. loop file lines, sum ratings by (userId, productId), and combine id_String and id_Int
val userIdMap = mutable.Map[String, Int]() // (userId, userIdAsInt)
val productIdMap = mutable.Map[String, Int]() // (productId, productIdAsInt)
val userProductRatingMap = mutable.Map[(Int, Int), Float]() // (userIdAsInt, productIdAsInt, ratingSum)

var userIdIndice = -1
var productIdIndice = -1

validLines.foreach(x => {
  val userIdString = x._1._1
  val userId = getIndice(userIdString, userIdIndice, userIdMap)
  userIdIndice = userId._2

  val productIdString = x._1._2
  val productId = getIndice(productIdString, productIdIndice, productIdMap)
  productIdIndice = productId._2

  val key = (userId._1, productId._1)
  userProductRatingMap.get(key) match {
    case Some(i) => userProductRatingMap += (key -> (i + x._2))
    case None => userProductRatingMap += (key -> x._2)
  }
})

filePrinter(FilePathPre + UserIdFile, userIdMap)
filePrinter(FilePathPre + ProductIdFile, productIdMap)
aggFilePrinter(FilePathPre + RatingFile, userProductRatingMap)
  }
}
```

Comment: You'd get more answers on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you want to know what the tech lead has in mind, the best person to ask would be the tech lead.

Comment: put at least one implicit ;)

Answer (score 0):

Apart of *javish* code you have also code style issues, suggest to read https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/ at the start (this is not an ultimate guide, but for start is ok). Avoid to use `._1` on tuples, use `match { case (a, b, c) => ... }` instead.

The main issue is that you use mutable structures, so in scala every structure is immutable by default and it should stay like that unless you have a strong reason to have it mutable. It is more about functional programming which from one perspective tries to avoid mutability and side effects, you can google for this topic more.

So remove `mutable.` from your code and replace `foreach` with eg. `foldLeft` to get newly created `immutable.Map` on each iteration instead of modifying existing one.

Comment: Hey, thank you for pointing out your opinion. I agree with you about mutable variable and ._1.